# Text Changed is called twice in windows phone application

Tags: c#, xaml, exception, windows-phone-8

In my App I have a screen which Consist of a TextBox,Listpicker and a LongListSelector.

LongListSelector contains a list of places with categories define.

we can sort the list by selecting the desired Category from listpicker or by typing text in the textbox which will search the list and give you desired list.

I have 10 categories , my code is working fine for 9 but in case of 10th category when I select and then type anything in searchbox and then erase it then my app crashes.

I have tried try catch everywhere but it directly goes to debugger,break and the exception it shows in debugger is

"Layout cycle detected. Layout could not complete."

my xaml code is :

```
  <phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
        <local:Number x:Key="Number"/>
        <DataTemplate x:Name="PickerFullItemTemplate">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" FontSize="36"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>

    <!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White" >
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->
        <Grid Grid.Row="0" Background="#132d63">
            <TextBlock Foreground="white" Text="{Binding Path=LocalizedResources.Places,Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}" Margin="0,6,0,8"  FontSize="40" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
        </Grid>
        <Grid Grid.Row="1" >
            <toolkit:PhoneTextBox Hint="{Binding Path=LocalizedResources.Search,Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}" Text="{Binding searchtextbox,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=Default}" TextChanged="Searchbox_TextChanged"  Name="Searchbox" FontSize="25" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Background="White" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1"/>
        </Grid>
        <Grid Grid.Row="2" Margin="12,0,12,0">
            <toolkit:ListPicker ExpansionMode="ExpansionAllowed" FullModeHeader="Categories" 
                    Name="listpicker" 
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Categories,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=Default}" FullModeItemTemplate="{StaticResource PickerFullItemTemplate}" SelectedItem="{Binding listpickerselecteditem,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=Default}" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Background="White" Foreground="Black" Margin="0,-5,0,0"/>
        </Grid>

        <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
        <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="3" Margin="12,0,0,0">
            <ls:LongListSelector1 x:Name="placesinfolist"  Margin="0,10,0,10" ItemsSource="{Binding attractionlist,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=Default}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedAttractionDetail,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=Default}" />
      </Grid>
</Grid>
```

and my code viewmodel is

```
public class AttractionViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        List<AttractionDetails> newsearchlist = new List<AttractionDetails>();
        Boolean Isgetattractionlist = false;        

        #region Properties

        ObservableCollection<AttractionDetails> attractionlistbackup { get; set; }

        private ObservableCollection<AttractionDetails> _attractionlist;
        public ObservableCollection<AttractionDetails> attractionlist
        {
            get
            {
                return _attractionlist;
            }
            set
            {
                _attractionlist = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("attractionlist");
            }
        }

        private bool _isLoading;
        public bool IsLoading
        {
            get
            {
                return _isLoading;
            }
            private set
            {
                _isLoading = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("IsLoading");

            }
        }

        private AttractionDetails _SelectedAttractionDetail;
        public AttractionDetails SelectedAttractionDetail
        {
            get
            {
                return _SelectedAttractionDetail;
            }
            set
            {
                int index = 0;
                _SelectedAttractionDetail = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedAttractionDetail");

                for (int i = 0; i < attractionlist.Count(); i++)
                {
                    if (attractionlist[i] == SelectedAttractionDetail)
                    {
                        index = i;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                Messenger.Default.Send<int>(index, "toattractiondetails");
                IsLoading = true;
                Messenger.Default.Send<ObservableCollection<AttractionDetails>>(attractionlist, "attractiondetails");
            }
        }

        private List<string> _Categories;
        public List<string> Categories
        {
            get
            {
                return _Categories;
            }
            set
            {
                _Categories = value;
            }
        }

        private string _searchtextbox;
        public string searchtextbox
        {
            get
            {
                return _searchtextbox;
            }
            set
            {
                try
                {
                    _searchtextbox = value;
                    //   RaisePropertyChanged("searchtextbox");                   

                    if (attractionlist == null)
                        attractionlist = new ObservableCollection<AttractionDetails>();
                    attractionlist.Clear();

                    if (listpickerselecteditem == null)
                    {
                        listpickerselecteditem = AppResources.All;
                    }

                    if (listpickerselecteditem == AppResources.All)
                    {
                        attractionlist.Clear();
                        foreach (var item in attractionlistbackup)
                        {
                            if (!(item.name.ToLowerInvariant().IndexOf(searchtextbox) == -1))
                            {
                                attractionlist.Add(item);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        attractionlist.Clear();
                        foreach (var item in attractionlistbackup)
                        {
                            string qwe = "";
                            qwe = item.categoryType;
                            qwe = qwe.Replace("\r\n", string.Empty);

                            if (!(item.name.ToLowerInvariant().IndexOf(searchtextbox) == -1) && listpickerselecteditem == qwe)
                            {
                                attractionlist.Add(item);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                }
            }
        }

        private string _listpickerselecteditem;
        public string listpickerselecteditem
        {
            get
            {
                return _listpickerselecteditem;
            }
            set
            {
                _listpickerselecteditem = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("listpickerselecteditem");

                if (attractionlist == null)
                    attractionlist = new ObservableCollection<AttractionDetails>();
                attractionlist.Clear();

                if (listpickerselecteditem == AppResources.All)
                {
                    foreach (var item in attractionlistbackup)
                    {
                        if (searchtextbox != null)
                        {
                            if (!(item.name.ToLowerInvariant().IndexOf(searchtextbox) == -1))
                            {
                                attractionlist.Add(item);
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            attractionlist.Add(item);
                        }
                    }
                }

                else
                {
                    foreach (var item in attractionlistbackup)
                    {
                        string qwe = "";
                        qwe = item.categoryType;
                        qwe = qwe.Replace("\r\n", string.Empty);

                        if (searchtextbox == null)
                        {
                            if (listpickerselecteditem == qwe)
                                attractionlist.Add(item);
                        }

                        else if (!(item.name.ToLowerInvariant().IndexOf(searchtextbox) == -1) && listpickerselecteditem == qwe)
                        {
                            attractionlist.Add(item);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        #endregion

        public AttractionViewModel()
        {
            Messenger.Default.Register<string>(this, "attraction", GetAttractions);
            Messenger.Default.Register<string>(this, "toplacesview", setlist);
        }

        public void setlist(string message)
        {
            if (searchtextbox != message)
            {
                searchtextbox = message;
            }
        }

        public void GetAttractions(string message)
        {

        }
    }
```

and my code behind is

```
public partial class Attractions : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        public Attractions()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Searchbox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                TextBox asd = sender as TextBox;
                Messenger.Default.Send<string>(asd.Text, "toplacesview");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        private void GotoAttractionDetails(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
        {
            AttractionDetailsPage.flag = 0;
            NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Skins/AttractionDetailsPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
        }
    }
```

One more thing textchanged event is fired twice every time text is changes I don't know why this is happening.

Please help.....