# Layouy Cycle Detected In Windows Phone 8 Exception?

Tags: c#, exception, windows-phone-8

I have a LongListSelector which contains a list of places and to sort them i have a listpicker and a textbox for search and listpicker to choose the category ..  but when I select some particular categories the goes directly to debugger.Break and exception it shows is LayOut Cycle Detected.

I am not able to detect this problem as it is not even caught in try/catch.

When I searched the net about this problem it says that you should not call any layout update event but case is not possible for me as my list has to be update according to the sort.

If have any Idea how to resolve this issue Please Help .....

Comment: You're right about the Layout Update event being the issue but you need to avoid executing layout code when you know it's going to fire. You'll need to post code but from what it sounds like, you're LayoutUpdate is firing, you're changing some layout items in that event handler which is causing that event handler to fire again (infinite loop).

Comment: @keyboardP you can check my code on this question ....
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17359672/text-changed-is-called-twice-in-windows-phone-application

Comment: If you remove the ListPicker or PhoneTextbox (try one at a time), does it still throw the error?

Comment: yes if i remove phonetextbox then it throws error when i change listpicker value .. or if i keep both then it dont throw any error on change in value of listpicker but throws error when i write something in textbox and then remove it ... like i write c so list comes sorted by c it works fine but when i ramove c then it throws error ....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found the Solution to the problem just needed to set the minimum height of the grids in the view ....

Comment: Just as an addition if someone else has the same issue: for me it was in a LongListSelector when image was UniformToFill but no height/width was given

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had made an error in my `ArrangeOverride` function. Somewhere I had a calculation that caused me to align the elements with a negative X and Y value (because I divided by the count of items minus two somewhere, and when 1 elements would be added, that would result in a negative number).

Positioning child elements at a negative left and top margin (at least outside the bounds) appears to trigger a new layout update, although I am unable to find the source on that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Loaded** event instead of Layout Update event so that you can get rid of this problem. It worked for me.